# Possible to retrieve uncommon list from two array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

The scenario is that I have to delete everything except selected values.
For example, I have two array as `allPeople` and `selectedPeople`.
I just need to extract unselected people list so that I can delete from *Realm*. Any Help?

```
var allPeople = ["Wayne", "Bryan", "Peter", "Jack", "Mario", "David", "Clark", "John"]

var selectedPeople = ["Peter", "Jack", "Mario", "David"]
```

expected result:

```
["Wayne", "Bryan", "Clark", "John"] // unselected people
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Naive (?) approach filtering the array

If your array is not going to grow to any huge size then you could do something like...

```
let unselectedPeople = people.filter { !selectedPeople.contains($0) }
```

This is not optimal for large arrays but for small arrays will be fine.

### Another approach using `Set`

If all the people are unique (which they would have to be to make your logic work). You could use `Set`.

```
let unselectedPeople = Set(people).subtracting(Set(selectedPeople))
```

This uses the `subtracting` api on `Set`... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/subtracting(_:)-3n4lc